# Small icon app list view osx

Tags: objective-c, macos, icons

In some applications like Sparrow Mail are set two different application icons. The default icon used in dock, in icon view e cover flow. Then a second smaller for list view, column view and title bar. How do you set the icon smaller? In file.plist there is only this.
Thanks.
[image]

[image: file.plist]

Comment: the ICNS icon file supports multiple resolutions. Did you try that? Could be the solution: [check here] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Icon_Image_format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode includes the Icon Composer.app application which allows you to create .icns (Icon Suite) files which support multiple resolutions like shown in the following image:

[image]

As you can see in the image above, the Get Info panel’s “proxy” icon (in the titlebar) is using the small 16 x 16 icon, while the lower icon is using one of the larger sizes. If you are used to the single-size-only ways of `UIImage`, how an `NSImage` works in OS X may be confusing at first. In iOS, a `UIImage` represents a single bitmap image, and is basically a wrapper around a CoreGraphics `CGImageRef`. An `NSImage` in OS X works at a higher level, and as such, is quite different than a `UIImage`. An `NSImage` contains one or more specifically-sized `NSImageRep`s, which are more analogous to a `UIImage`. In the screenshot you provided, both the window title bar button’s image and the `NSImageView`’s image are set to the same instance of an `NSImage`. When that image is asked to draw itself, however, the image is choosing 2 different `NSImageRep`s based on the size requested. For more information on how this works, see [Cocoa Drawing Guide: Image Basics - How an Image Representation is Chosen](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Images/Images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH208-BCIGEIFF).

If you’re using the all-in-one Xcode.app app bundle, launch Xcode and choose Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Icon Composer. If you’re using the older style of the Xcode tools, with multiple folders, it’ll be at `<Developer Tools>/Applications/Utilities/Icon Composer.app`.

Comment: I don't need to create file.icns but how to add different icons. For example, in IOS you can add different resolutions, and in OSX?
Check here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ qa/qa1686/_index.html